# Flask SqlAlchemy begin and end transaction

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm writing a SqlAlchemy transaction in flask using sqlalchemy extension:

```
flask.ext.sqlalchemy
```

Here's how my code looks like:

```
def charge_user(user):
  db.session.begin()
  try:
    transaction = create_transaction()
    if not transaction:
      // cancel the session
      return False

    db.session.add(transaction)
    user.paid = True
    db.session.add(user)
    return True
  except Exception:
    db.session.rollback()
    return False
```

Just one quick question, the documentation of sqlalchemy extension vs the flask-sqlalchemy plugin are very confusing. How do I do cancel the session/transaction in case of flask-sqlalchemy extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I do cancel the session/transaction in case of flask-sqlalchemy extension.

That's what `db.session.rollback()` does.